# Использование тега селект

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте, пишу сайтик, в новостях используются разделы, в редакторе надо соответственно сделать выбор к какой категории относиться сайт.

Вопрос в чём, как сделать

```
<select>
<option>новости</option>
<option>не новости</option>
<option>про новости</option>
</select>
```

Из базы дергаются данные, в том числе к какой категории относится новость. как на хтмл+пхп сделать пункт который получен из базы "по умолчанию" чтобы не нужно было при редактировании опять выставлять категорию новости?

UPD:

```
Mysql: table news
id(autoink)
date(datetime)
autor(enum=admin,moderator)
postPreview(varchar100)
post(varchar255)
category(enum=newscat1, newscat2, newscat3, no default)

<?
include(config);
mysql_connect(host, log, pass);
mysql_select_db(base);
q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=$_GET[id]")
while(FALSE!==(res=mysql_fetch_assoc(q)) { ?>
<html>
<form method=post>
<select>
<option>News Cat1</option>
<option>News Cat2</option>
<option>News Cat3</option>
</select>
<textarea><? echo $res[postpreview]; ?></textarea>
<textarea><? echo $res[post]; ?></textarea>
<input type=submit />
</form>
```

Если в общем то вот так сейчас это примерно всё и написано.

Comment: <a href="http://tsya.ru">http://tsya.ru</a>

Comment: спасибо, русский знаю, иногда бывает, на автопилоте)

Comment: вопрос закрыт, всем спасибо, кто откликнулся)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$newscat = 15; // получить из новости
$news_arr = array(
  /*
  список селекта , категории в виде:
    id: идентификатор категории,
    name: имя категории
  (я не знаю, как у вас называются эти поля, может, будет $obj['categoryID'], если категория - массив, а не объект)
  */
  );
echo '<select>';
foreach ($news_arr as $n => $obj)
  echo '<option value="'.$obj->id.'"'.($newscat==$obj->id?' selected="selected"':'').'>'.$obj->name.'</option>';
echo '</select>';
```

---

Пример записи:

```
$cat = new stdClass();
$cat->id = 15;
$cat->name = 'Категория например';
```

Такой же результат будет возвращен запросом вида

```
$cat = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query('SELECT id, name FROM ...'));
```

Comment: он получает из массива список вариантов новостей, и там, где он совпадёт с полученым из базы,делает его "selected"? а еще откуда берётся ID? даже не так, объект это имя из массива, что  есть $n и id

Comment: видимо совсем не понял, можно по русски откуда беруться какие переменные?

Comment: Обновил. 

>Из базы дергаются данные, в том числе к какой категории относится новость.`

Вот из этого сделал вывод, что у вас есть и родительская категория редактируемой новости (`$newscat`) и список всех категорий (`$news_arr`)

Comment: пример как должен выглядеть массив можно? то есть семл на пару ID новостей скажем так.

Comment: так, ладно, ничего не понял, но прикольно) за труды + и правильный ответ, осталось мне покурить код)) вроде всё понятно, но ничего не понятно))

Comment: если не сложно, примерный рабочий семпл на demorian@list.ru скинуть, буду очень благодарен:)

Comment: Обновил) А вообще лучше допишите в вопрос свои данные (`print_r($category)`, например), я подтяну код.

Comment: <a href="http://sh4dow.jino.ru/111.php">Тут</a> пару дней будет рабочий код.

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант использовать фрэймворк. Если php фрэймворк, например Zend Framework, то там должно быть это реализовано нативными методами. Есть вариант сделать это через javascript в частности jquery framework:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yourSelectId').val('<?=$selectValue ?>');
});
```

Comment: интересует именно модель php+html

Answer (score 1):

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT variant, default FROM variants');

$variants = array();    //массив в который положим категории
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $variants[] = $row; //собственно ложим...
}
```

Данные готовы, отрисовываем:

```
include_once 'myTemplate.html';
/*
 *    подключаем html шаблончик(можно прямо в скрипте)
 *    но это ИМХО убого :)
 */
```

Сам шаблончик:

```
<select>
   <?foreach($variants as $variant):?>
     <!-- Допустим что дефолтное значение у нас всегда = 1 а остальные 0-->
      <?if($variant['default'] == 1):?>
<option value="<?=$variant['variant']?>" selected><?=$variant['variant']?></option>
      <?endif?>
      <?if($variant['default'] == 0):?>
          <option value="<?=$variant['variant']?>"><?=$variant['variant']?></option>
      <?endif?>
   <?endforeach?>
</select>
```

если правильно понял то вот както так...

Comment: Аааа так вот кто пишет шаблоны в стиле php3 `>_<`

Comment: ага, а вы случаем не один из рабов шаблонизаторов?:)<br>
или по вашему<br>
>  `echo '<option value="'.$obj->id.'"'.($newscat==$obj->id?' >  selected="selected"':'').'>'.$obj->name.'</option>';
>echo '</select>';`<br> крута написано? xDDD<br><br>
Уважаемый кагби php сам по себе является шаблонизатором это раз<br> два - я не спрашивал у вас как мне оформлять вывод...<br>
три - юзать шаблонизатор в шаблонизаторе я не собираюсь

Comment: Я не об этом. У вас IF индийский, а оформление как в книжках по пхп3 конца 90х. Если бы вы по ссылке прочитали, там как раз написано, что я не перевариваю шаблонизаторы кроме нативных.
Просто периодически модули джумлы так оформлены, а подсветка работает на `{}` и искать соответствующий `endif` дико запаривает.

Comment: табуляцией нормально отделять, не?<br> И зачем вы коснулись религиозных вопросов я не понимаю, вот мне например тоже ненравится как у вас написано, но я же не кричу в коментах что вы по индейски написали :)<br>К чему этот акт агрошкольничества?

Comment: Омфг, я говорю о том, что у вас лишние операторы(это как раз про индийский IF) и такой код неудобно редактировать при бОльшем ветвлении. Для того чтобы добавить option'у параметр или изменить значение, его надо прописывать дважды. При 4-5 подряд идущих условиях сложно искать конец ветки даже с подсветкой. Это вопрос не религии, а качества.

Comment: Вам в голову не приходило что я так написал <b>ДЛЯ НАГЛЯДНОСТИ</b>?<br><small>Может достаточно тупого агра, не?</small>

Comment: Лимит каментов. Да я не агрюсь, просто учитывайте, что люди так и будут писать. Мне не "не нравится", просто лично на этом потерял дофига времени и нервов, вот и дернулся глаз сейчас от такого)

Comment: Если бы я здесь начал описывать то, как я организовываю вывод в шаблон - мой ответ был бы чрезмерно огромным, я описал алгоритм решения данной проблемы, как им пользоваться уже дело каждого...<br>
Я просто знаю что абсолютно большинство начинающих программистов мягко говоря не дружат с тернарным оператором, именно поэтому мой ответ выглядит именно так... Надеюсь что вопрос исчерпан...

Answer (score 0):

Всё просто до усрачки...

```
<select name="sex">
<option value="male" <?php if ($sex=='male') echo 'selected'; ?> >Мужской</option>
  <option value="female" <?php if ($sex=='female') echo 'selected'; ?> >Женский</option>
  </select>
```

Всем спасибо!